# CosmosDB Create Table hanging indefinately

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I've tried all four variations of the methods that create a table:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
var task = table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
task.Wait();
return table;
```

The Azure Storage Explorer created a table without any delay.

There's no timeout or other exception, just hangs.

Any ideas?  I'm struggling to think of how to debug it.

I've tried this in an ASP.NET application and in a console application.
I've tried the async and sync forms of the methods.
I've tried using `async`/`await` and explicitly waiting the returned task from the async forms.

**NB**
Same behaviour with the demo applications at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-table-dotnet-core-getting-started.git

Answer (score 0):

Never used `.Wait()` (or `.Result`) especially if it's coming from a UI thread (or Controller method) as it can cause a deadlock.

Change your method to an `async Task<T>`.

Example:

```
public async Task<Table> CreateTableIfNotExistsAsync()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

    var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
    await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    return table;
}
```

If there is no way you can turn this into an async code then you can try `ConfigureAwait(false)` but this will only work if anything that calls this method and any method this is calling is also using it.

```
public Table CreateTableIfNotExists()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

    var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
    table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return table;
}
```

Comment: I've tried the async forms and the synchronous forms.  No difference.  I've also tried it in an ASP.NET application and a Console application.

Comment: Are you sure the db is accessible over the network? Which is the line that is causing the hanging?

Comment: `GetTableReference` is fine and the Azure Storage Explorer is able to create tables.

Comment: So which line hangs?

Comment: `CreateIfNotExistsAsync`, also `CreateAsync` and their synchronous forms.

Comment: It 100% has to do with the synchronization context. Can't see any other reason.

Comment: Ditto, can't think what though.

Comment: I don't have the whole code to help. Can do if you upload a console app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191250/discussion-between-banksysan-and-nick-chapsas).